# Is there a performance benchmarking tool for Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: benchmarking, hyperledger

I would like to do some performance benchmarking with the Hyperledger Fabric (e.g. avg. transaction execution time in a 4-node chain with PBFT). Is there a tool for that, or should i use JMeter or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several days ago IBM released Busywork exerciser framework for the Hyperledger Fabric. 
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/tools/busywork

As it mentioned in description “**busywork** applications can be used both for correctness and performance testing, as well as for simple benchmarks.”

Comment: The link is dead, and here is the new URL? 
https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/tree/master/tools/busywork

Comment: Is there any other tool for performance bench-marking or stress testing fabric?

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-test/tree/master/tools/PTE Has a variety of stress test cases.